# How to update individual array element in firebase with iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Here i'm using firestore query to update, insert data. How to upadate dictionary of array value to firebase database.

here is my firestore data structure: [image]

Right now able to get data of **slot1 -> 0th position value** in a model class. 
how can i update value of slot1 **0th position** of **isbooked boolean value alone**, **without affecting remaining values and other slot**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't without reading the entire document, modifying the array data in memory, then updating the entire array field back out do the document.  The smallest unit of change in a Firestore array field is an *entire* field.  You can't make smaller changes to individual elements of a field, **except** those defined by [arrayUnion](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/FieldValue#arrayunion_) and [arrayRemove](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/FieldValue#arrayremove_) (which are not compatible with what you're trying to do here).

Comment: do you mean the whole slotName dictionary or slot1 arrray? can you help me out of this?

Comment: The array.  I already said what you have to do - read the document, make changes in memory, write the field back out.

Comment: @Mac_Play still i didnt find answer for this. So i asked backend developer to update it

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by getting the exact id of your structure ..

```
Database.database().reference().child("SlotName").child(yourAry.key).child(yourAry.key).child("isbooked").setValue(true/false)
```

Manage your database structure accordingly, its just an example and as user Doug suggested have a look on docs too ..